# How do I create a persistent tunnel device in sles15 (with or without wicked xml config)

Tags: ssh-tunneling, sles, tunneling

I'm trying to simplify some of my configs for sles15, pushing out tunnel configs to my machines via ansible.  Currently whenever I configure a tunnel, I do it on the fly using ssh from the machine initiating the ssh tunnel and sudo commands (running tunctl (which isn't there any more).

What I'd like to do is have the tunnel persistent on the sles15 machine and then just connect to it with ssh and the -w command.

However, this doesn't work worth a crap:

```
<interface>
  <link-type>tun</link-type>
  <name>tun1</name>
  <control>
    <mode>boot</mode>
  </control>
  <firewall/>
  <tun>
    <owner>ansible</owner>
    <group>sshinternalusers</group>
  </tun>

  <ipv4>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <forwarding>true</forwarding>
  </ipv4>
  <ipv6>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <forwarding>false</forwarding>
  </ipv6>
</interface>
```

and this doesn't work either (which I think is the traditional way of doing it)

```
STARTMODE='onboot'
BOOTPROTO='static'
TUNNEL_SET_PERSISTENT='yes'
TUNNEL='tun'
TUNNEL_LOCAL_IPADDR=172.20.26.115
TUNNEL_REMOTE_IPADDR=172.20.26.114
TUNNEL_DEVICE=tun0
TUNNEL_SET_OWNER=ansible
TUNNEL_SET_GROUP=sshinternalusers
```

I haven't found any documentation on the XML (other than reverse engineering the schema).  The tunnel does appear to start when I reboot the machine, but there has to be a different way to get the tunnel up because when I run ifup tun0 it tells me "no device"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out what the heck wicked is doing is by making the old fashioned network config scripts (which are documented with `man ifcfg-tunnel`)

add this:

```
STARTMODE='auto'
BOOTPROTO='static'
TUNNEL_SET_PERSISTENT='yes'
TUNNEL='tun'
IPADDR=172.20.26.115
REMOTE_IPADDR=172.20.26.114
TUNNEL_DEVICE=tun0
TUNNEL_SET_OWNER=ansible
TUNNEL_SET_GROUP=sshinternalusers
ZONE=public
MTU=1300
```

as /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-tun0

run `wicked ifup tun0`

and the tunnel should appear in `ip addr show`

now (and this is based off of some powerpoint suse released to show how cool wicked is)

cd to /etc/sysconfig/network

run `wicked show-config compat:`

this'll spit out the interface files for whatever is in this directory (i.e. ifcfg-tun0)

put that output, which may look like:

```
<interface >
  <name>tun1</name>
  <control>
    <mode>auto</mode>
  </control>
  <firewall>
    <zone>public</zone>
  </firewall>
  <tun>
    <owner>479</owner>
    <group>479</group>
  </tun>
  <link>
    <mtu>1300</mtu>
  </link>
  <ipv4>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <forwarding>true</forwarding>
  </ipv4>
  <ipv4:static>
    <address>
      <local>172.20.42.115/32</local>
      <peer>172.20.42.114</peer>
    </address>
  </ipv4:static>
  <ipv6>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <forwarding>false</forwarding>
  </ipv6>
</interface>
```

in /etc/wicked/ifconfig/tun0.xml and delete the old config file from sysconfig

if you do `wicked ifreload tun0`

it should be using the new config now, you can reboot or wicked ifdown/ifup to make sure.

**Note, owner and group are the ID's, not the usernames**

and, since you're using ssh, don't forget to set `PermitTunnel Yes` in the sshd config file.

---

FWIW (and not much since you don't want to use this manually when running wicked) the replacement for `tunctl` appears to be `ip tunnel`.